# How to remove hexane from nBuLi

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

As described in a paper, the authors removed the hexane from the nBuLi solution "under reduced pressure".
I was wondering if anyone had any experience on how to proceed safely with this procedure. I was also wondering if anyone could confirm to me that nBuLi not in hexane and under vacuum is indeed stable.

Flower, K. R.; McGown, A. T.; Miles, P. J.; Pritchard, R. G.; Warren, J. E. Isolation of $\ce{1,4-Li2-C6H4}$ and Its Reaction with $\ce{[(Ph3P)AuCl]}$. *Dalton Trans.* **2010**, *39* , 3509. https://doi.org/10.1039/b925355f.

Comment: Once upon a time solid butyllithium was commercially available, so yes it is stable if air and moisture are rigourously excluded

Comment: You state only a part of the story.  But once hexane is removed under reduced pressure (Schlenk line?), what do you want to do?  Maybe the swap of solvents (just a guess) is not necessary as nBuLi equally is commercially available as a solution in diethyl ether, THF, etc. And of course, the scale of the intended operation (both volume and initial concentration of the solution to «process» -- 10 mL 2M in hexanes is easier to manage than the 11 M stock).

Comment: Thanks! @Buttonwood This question was more out of curiosity on how the authors of the paper managed to remove the hexane from the nBuLi/Hexane solution without it catching on fire. From the other answer it seems possible they dried it on the schlenk line.